# Printing a word from a file that is misspelled in Python

Tags: python

So I am looking to print out the words from a sample file that are misspelled and I cant seem to figure out how to loop through 2 lists together. Here's the code: (the top is just a helper function) and dict.txt is just a long list of every possible word

```
def cleanWords(wlist):
    ret=[]
    for word in wlist:
        cleanword = word.strip('?.,;:!\'-"\n()')
        ret.append(cleanword.lower())
    return ret

f = open('dict.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
cleanlistdic = cleanWords(lines)

inword = raw_input("Enter a file name: ")
g = open(inword, 'r')
lines2 = g.readlines()
cleanlistfile = cleanWords(lines2)

# this part is where i get stuck
for line in cleanlistfile:
    for j in cleanlistdic:
        if line not in cleanlistdic:
            print line
```

Answer (score 0):

You inner loop is pointless (as evidenced by you never using `j`).

You just need the single loop: for each `line`, print it if it is not in `cleanlistdic`.

Comment: And now it is just printing all of the words in the test file. Any suggestions?

Comment: for line in cleanlistfile:
    if (line not in cleanlistdict):
        print line

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to accomplish this task:

```
desired_lines = [line for line in cleanlistfile if line not in cleanlistdic]
```

If you to print each line, you can use a for loop:

```
for line in desired_lines:
     print line
```